# aws lambda expression with alexa skills

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am able to invoke the lambda expression using Alexa sdk, but unable to call the external service from the lambda expression.  I am not getting any error or response.  I'm not sure what's wrong with this. 
While testing the lambda expression I'm only able to get the logs until 'Do the POST call', not after that.  That means something wrong in https.request.
The same logic tested with node.js is able to get the response correctly. Any thoughts?

```
    var https = require('https');
    var responseString = ''; 

    var postheaders = {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'//,
        //'Content-Length' : Buffer.byteLength(jsonObject, 'utf8')
    };

    var optionspost = {
        host : '{host name}',
        port : 443,
        path : '{path name}',
        method : 'POST',
        headers : postheaders
    };

    console.info('Options prepared:');
    //console.info(optionspost);
    console.info('Do the POST call');

    // do the POST call
    var reqPost = https.request(optionspost, function(res) {

        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        // uncomment it for header details
        // console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

        res.on('data', function(d) {
            console.info('POST result:\n');
            process.stdout.write(d);
            responseString += d;
            console.info('\n\nPOST completed');
        });

        res.on('error', function(e) {
            console.error('error');
            console.error(e);
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            console.info('end');       
            var responseObject = JSON.parse(responseString);

            if (responseObject.error) {
                console.info("NOAA error: " + responseObject.error.message);        
            } else {
                console.info(responseString);             
            }
         });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.error('Communications err' + e);
        console.error(e);
    }); 

reqPost.end();
reqPost.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
}).on('error', function (e) {
        console.log("Communications error: " + e.message);        
});
```